# How to chain two CSS transitions on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, callback, transition

I am trying to make an animation where I translate a slideshow **without** a transition. Then translate the same slideshow but **with** a transition.

I been trying different methods and this was the only solution I found so the first transition and transform executed first, then the second transition and transform.
How bad is it?

```
slideshow.style.transition = `none`;
slideshow.style.transform = `translateX(-1000px)`;

setTimeout(() => {
    slideshow.style.transition = `.5s ease-out all`;
    slideshow.style.transform = `translateX(0)`;
},10);
```

I know there are CSS Callbacks, but when I tried them, didn't work as intended.

Comment: How didn't the callbacks work? Was it late? Early? Never run? Error?

Comment: Also, you can use that setTimeout if you just set the right amount of delay (500 in this case).

Comment: I am sorry, I had a mistake in the code published. I edited, as you can see the transition is set to none so the first transform has no transition.

So when I ran the callbacks the problem was that the callback never run, I think because being a transition none it doesn't count the translate.

Comment: Well if there isn’t a transition... it’ll just... happen... no need for a delay or callback

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong in doing this. But.. if you chain your transitions in Css, the browser won't need to do any extra calculations and your animations will be smoother than butter..
I.e:

for an element that has a 'position: relative' property, top, right, bottom, left does not affect the document layout and can be used together with the transform property for ultra-smooth transitions and animations..

transforn: translateY(1000px)
top: - 1000px
`transition: top 0s linear 2s`(it will take 2s before the element jumps by 1000px)`, transform 1s ease 2s`(the element will slide for 1s after a 2s delay, which will make it appear to be looping with the instant jump of the top property..) `

Hope it helps somewhat :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it all in JS you could substitute a requestAnimationFrame for the setTimeout.

This gets the slideshow translated by -1000px but at the next possible opportunity it starts to translate it back to 0, no need to wait for a (fairly random) 10ms.

```js
const slideshow = document.querySelector('.slideshow');
slideshow.style.transition = `none`;
slideshow.style.transform = `translateX(-1000px)`;

requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    slideshow.style.transition = `.5s ease-out all`;
    slideshow.style.transform = `translateX(0)`;
});
```

```html
<div class="slideshow" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: blue;"></div>
```

Alternatively you could look at using a CSS animation with duration 0.5s rather than a transition as this will start by translating the element and then start to move it to its final position without need for a callback.

```
@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-1000px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```